# Jave Equivalent impementation of withColumn in Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to use function which are available in `org.apache.spark.sql.functions`

When I am using it as

```
Dataset<Row> dfSelect =sqlContext.sql(
"SELECT unix_timestamp(concat(Date,' ',regexp_replace(Time,'[.]',':'))) AS TIMESTAMP,
`NMHC(GT)` from airQuality");
```

These functions are working fine as they should but when I am using 
`Dataset<Row> org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withColumn(String colName, Column col)`
function in Java, i have implemented as below but it is giving error

```
Dataset<Row> df = spark.read().format("csv")
                .option("dateFormat", "dd/MM/yyyy")
                .option("timeFormat", "hh.mm.ss")
                .option("mode", "PERMISSIVE")
                .option("inferSchema", true)
                .option("header", true)
                .schema(schema)
                .load("src/main/resources/AirQualityUCI/AirQualityUCI.csv");
        df.createOrReplaceTempView("airQuality");
        df.withColumn("DateStamp",unix_timestamp(concat(df.col("Date"),col(" "),regexp_replace(df.col("Time"),"[.]",":"))));
```

Error is

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '` `' given input columns: [Time,  Date];;
'Project [Date#0, Time#1, unix_timestamp(concat(Date#0, ' , regexp_replace(Time#1, [.], :)), yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss) AS DateStamp#32]
+- Relation[Date#0,Time#1] csv
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.package$AnalysisErrorAt.failAnalysis(package.scala:42)
```

Comment: check this https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/test/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/DatasetSuite.scala you will get lot of examples of how to do that

Comment: I already know how to do implement `withColumn` in scala but unable to interpret its java equivalent. @RamGhadiyaram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue probably lies in the `concat`

```
        concat(df.col("Date"),col(" "),regexp_replace(df.col("Time"),"[.]",":"))
```

And more precisely inside the `col(" ")` which instructs the SQL engine to find a column (hence the `col` function) whose name is `" "` (space character). And of course, no such columns exist, which is why you get an error saying there is no such column :

```
cannot resolve '` `' given input columns: [Time,  Date];;
```

If what you want, as I suspect, is a blank character inside your concatenation, you may express that with a literal column value, which is `lit(" ")` in spark.

Which would give :

```
        concat(df.col("Date"),lit(" "),regexp_replace(df.col("Time"),"[.]",":"))
```

In any case, my advice when dealing with such errors would be to simplify your expression untill it works, thus identifying what is at fault.

Comment: It worked but what is the meaning of first argument of `withColumn` as I am not able to see this change by `df.show()` or any new column creation named as  "Timestamp".

Comment: The first argument is the name of the created column. You can not see the results because each call to a dataframe creates a new one. Therefore you shoud do `df2 = df.withColumn(xxx); df2.show()` if you want to see the results of the `withColumn` action.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col;
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.regexp_replace;
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.concat;
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.unix_timestamp;
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit;

//Display date and time
df.withColumn("DateTime",concat(col("Date"),lit(" "),
       regexp_replace(col("Time"),"[.]",":"))).show(false);

//Display unix timestamp
df.withColumn("DateTimeUnix",unix_timestamp(concat(col("Date"),lit(" "),
       regexp_replace(col("Time"),"[.]",":")),"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")).show(false);
```